# Android: Getting the Value of RadioButton from Custom View

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I Have created a Custom view for the Radio Button Like this.
How can i get the value of RadioButton from the custom view and want to select one radio Button at a time.

```
public void getData(){
    cappingLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Capping capping: productList.getCappingList()){
        if (getActivity()!=null) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.product_capping, cappingLayout, false);
            cappingRadio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_product_detail_capping);
            cappingRadio.setText(capping.getCapping_type());
            cappingLayout.addView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Product_capping.xml

```
<RadioButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_product_detail_capping"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Normal"/>
```

I want to get a value of Radio Button after the Button click.

Comment: By Value, do you mean the text associated with the radio button?

Comment: yes. I have retrieve the data from server but cannot get the value of checked radioButton on button click event

Comment: you can use `radioButton.isChecked` to see if it was checked or not, or `radioButton.getText` to get content, described under that radio button

Comment: `cappingRadio` is your radio button, get it's value when you need. Or I don't get what's a problem.

Comment: It didn't work on custom view. I have checked both ischecked and getText. But thanks for commenting.

Comment: I tried to get the value on Button click event. it give null exception

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
  rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int childCount = group.getChildCount();
                for (int x = 0; x < childCount; x++) {
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(x);

                    if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {

                        System.out.println(btn.getText().toString());


                }

            }
        });
```

Or you can get the value manuel like this;

```
    public void hesap(View view) {

    if(rb1.isChecked())
        hsp.setText("rb1 Value");
    if(rb2.isChecked())
        hsp.setText("rb2 Value");
    if(rb3.isChecked())
        hsp.setText("rb3 Value");
    }
```

Comment: Can you search `holder` , maybe it can work. Or you can send the value to public class, and you can get, use where you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put radio button in radio group like below in xml file

```
<RadioGroup
              android:id="@+id/rg_gender"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
                 <RadioButton
                      android:id="@+id/rb_male"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:text="@string/male"
                      android:textColor="@color/col_white"
                      android:textSize="16dp" />
                  <RadioButton
                      android:id="@+id/rb_female"
                      android:text="@string/female"
                      android:textColor="@color/col_white"
                      android:textSize="16dp" />
         </RadioGroup>
```

then you can retrieve selected radio button from radio group like below in java file

```
rg_gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.rb_male) {
                    gender = "male";
                } else {
                    gender = "female";
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have been using custom view so it doesn't work as the radio button is created according to the data